# Convexity and continuity imply subdifferentiability

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

It is well-known that differentiability implies the continuity. I am looking for the converse and found the following result.

> **Theorem:** (Prop 2.36 page 85 [1]) If the convex function $f : X \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ is continuous
> at $x_0$, then $f$ is subdifferentiable at this point.

Here are some of their main arguments.

> *Proof.*
> Let $H$ be the convex epigraph of the function $f$. Since $f$ is continuous and "bla-bla-bla", there exists a closed supporting hyperplane of $H$ which passes through $(x_0,f (x_0))$, i.e. there exists $(x_0^*, \alpha_0)\in
> X^*\times \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\alpha_0[f(x)-f(x_0)]+ \langle
> x_0^*, x-x_0\rangle \geq 0, \forall x\in \text{dom} f$$
> that is
> $$f(x)\geq f(x_0)+ \langle
> \frac{-x_0^*}{\alpha_0}, x-x_0\rangle, \forall x\in \text{dom} f$$
> So $-x_0^*/\alpha_0$ is a sub-gradient, thus, $f$ is subdifferentiable at $x_0$.

**My question** is how we know that $$\alpha_0> 0?$$

---

[1] https://epdf.tips/convexity-and-optimization-in-banach-spaces2e1fcb978b857bf00941909fa1d4b09541927.html

Comment: You don't. If the supporting hyperplane is not vertical, then you can always set $\alpha_0 = 1$.  Any non-vertical hyperplane through $(x_0,y_0)$ is the graph of $$y = y_0 + \langle x^*_0, x-x_0\rangle $$ for some $x_0^*$. Therefore, if $f$ is convex and its epigraph has at least one non-vertical supporting hyperplane at $(x_0,f(x_0)$, then there exists $x_0^*$ such that  $$ f(x) \ge f(x_0) + \langle x_0^*, x-x_0\rangle.$$

Comment: @Deane could you please explain what you mean by "you don't"? If I understand correctly, you are going to propose a new proof?!

Comment: @Deane showing the existence of the non-vertical supporting hyperplane is actually the main goal here, so your arguments do not much convince me.

Comment: If $f(x_0) < \infty$, a vertical supporting hyperplane implies $f = \infty$ on the other side of the hyperplane and therefore $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.

Comment: I foud here a doc https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_notes.pdf

see section "Existence of subgradients"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\alpha=0$. Then
$$
\langle x_0^*, x-x_0\rangle \ge 0
$$
for all $x\in \ dom \ f$. The point $x_0$ is an interior point of $dom \ f$, since $f$ is assumed to be continuous at $x_0$.
Hence $x-x_0$ can be taken from a small ball around zero. But then $x_0^*$ has to be zero. This is a contradiction to $(\alpha,x^*) \ne (0,0)$.

I suspect that the original inequality is
$$
\alpha (r - f(x_0)) + 
\langle x_0^*, x-x_0\rangle \ge 0
$$
for all $(x,r) \in epi \ f$.
And not the one in the question. Setting $x:=x_0$ and $r:=f(x_0)+1$ implies $\alpha \ge0$.

Comment: thanks but could you please explain more? e.g. why it must be an interior point and what about the case $\alpha<0$? Regarding $(\alpha, x^*)\neq 0$ do you mean $(\alpha, x_0^*)\neq (0, 0)$?

Comment: see edits......

Comment: thanks again! Note: The notations  $r, t, f$ are inconsistent.